# I don't know how to keep it dirty ('it' is an ActiveRecord model btw)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

Check this out:

```
  it "should not be this tough" do
    was = obj.association_id
    expect(obj.association_id).to eq 1
    obj.association_id = 2 * was
    expect(obj.association_id).to eq 2
    expect(obj.association_id_changed?).to be_true
    expect(obj.association_id_was).to be_present
  end
```

The last expectation fails. Why is that? If I go through the same steps in the console it works as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `attribute_was` method will look for the value the attribute had when it was persisted for the last time. If you haven't persisted the attribute, it will return `false` if you run `.present?` or expect it to `be_present`.

So, in your case, I would assume you're either just writing expectations on an object that has only been instantiated but not saved, or you have saved the object with an empty or nil value for `association_id`.